# Cant Get Dropdown Menu Background Extended As Per Text Length in Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to code this navbar but stuck at this issue where I am unable to extend the background/border of sub-menu as per its text length.

[Check screenshot here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ixYe.png)

```css
  
*{margin:0;padding:0}
#navbar{max-width:900px;width:100%;clear:both}
#navbar ul{border-top:#e82424 dashed 1px;border-bottom:#e82424 dashed 1px;background:#eee;width:100%;list-style:none;position:relative;float:left}
#navbar ul a,#navbar ul ul a{display:block;color:#000;text-decoration:none;font-size:16px;padding:5px 10px}
#navbar ul li{position:relative;float:left}
#navbar ul li.current-menu-item{background:#ddd}
#navbar ul li:hover{background:#f6f6f6}
#navbar ul ul{white-space:nowrap;min-width:100%;border:#e82424 dashed 1px;display:none;position:absolute;top:100%;left:0}
#navbar ul ul li{float:none}
#navbar ul ul ul{top:0;left:100%}
#navbar ul li:hover > ul{display:block}
```

```html
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Sub Menu 2 (Making it little longer)</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Deep Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="last-menu-item"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

http://jsbin.com/xogebiv/edit?html,output

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
#navbar ul{
   border-top:#e82424 dashed 1px;
   border-bottom:#e82424 dashed 1px;
   background:#eee;
   width:100%;
   list-style:none;
   position:relative;
   float:left
}
```

to

```
#navbar > ul{
   border-top:#e82424 dashed 1px;
   border-bottom:#e82424 dashed 1px;
   background:#eee;
   width:100%;
   list-style:none;
   position:relative;
   float:left
}
```

basically, do not apply the width: 100% to all ul's but only the first child.

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/suvizoqiwi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks, now the width of deep menu one and deep menu two border is not as per text length. Deep menu width is equal to longest submenu.